# Homomorphism and linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Decide if each $h: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is linear.

Why is this linear:
$$h\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
but this is not linear:
$$h\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $h:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is linear, then it satisfies
$$h\left(\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ b\\ c
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z
\end{bmatrix}\right)=h\left(\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ b\\ c
\end{bmatrix}\right)+h\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
for every two elements $\Bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr],\Bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr]$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is this true for your second example?

Comment: What do you mean by satisfies? As in they are equal to 0,0? Sorry I don't really understand, would you mind simplifying your explanation?

Comment: This is an equation. I am saying the thing on the left side must always be equal to the thing on the right side, no matter what the numbers $a,b,c,x,y,z$ are. Do you understand that vector addition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ works this way:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\ \vdots\\ a_n
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ \vdots\\ x_n
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+x_1\\ \vdots\\ a_n+x_n
\end{bmatrix}$$
For example, can you compute
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes it is 2 2 But I don't see what this has to do with 
0\\0  being linear but not the other one

Comment: In the second example, we are told that
$$h\left(\begin{bmatrix}
d\\ e\\ f
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
for **every** $\Bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}d\\ e\\ f\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr]$. So what is the left side of the equation in my answer going to be? What is the right side going to be? Are they equal?

Comment: clearer: $f(\alpha x) \neq \alpha f(x)$ for every $\alpha \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We call a function $f$ from one vector space to another *linear* if it satisfies two properties:

1. For all pairs of vectors $u,v$ in the domain, $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$.
2. For all vectors $u$ in the domain, and all scalars $k$, $f(ku)=kf(u)$.

The first example happens to satisfy this, because $h(x,y,z)=(0,0)$ for *all* $x,y,z$.  Since $(0,0)+(0,0)=(0,0)$ and $k(0,0)=(0,0)$, both properties are satisfied.  However this works only because $(0,0)$ is special in this way; any other choice won't work.